# C# WPF Kill a Process after x time: IvalidOperationException: Process Terminated

Tags: c#, wpf, process, waitforexit

I know,  I know,  there are many questions and good answers on how to kill a process after x time in C#.

However after reading and writing the code to achieve this task,  I find that is impossible to kill a process after a X time.  Due to my novice in C#,  I find difficult to understand the cause of error and correct it.

The task I want to achieve is to kill a process after 40 minutes,  that process is started by a button click.  I'm writing to the console:

```
private void click_start(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  using(Process p = Process.Start(@"calc.exe");
  {
   try{
      p.WaitForExit(5000);
      if(!p.HasExited) {
        p.kill();
        Console.WriteLine("Kill process waitforexit is false");
       } else {
        Console.WriteLine("NO Kill, waitforexit is true");
       }
     }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       Messageox.Show(ex.Messaage);
    }
}
```

Of all the answers in SO, this is the generalized accepted answer.

When running the code on VS 2015,  the debugger gives me this error:
"Can't process the request because the Process is finished."
Also always get the same console line: No kill which indicates that WaitForExit is still true.  This after waiting more than 10 minutes event the time to kill is set to less than one minute.

So I don't understand: I launched the process but when ordered to kill,  it's yet finished?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
if(!p.WaitForExit(5000))
    p.kill();
```

I'm not sure about dynamics of your process, but, especially during debugging, 
you might have relatively significant delays between one call or another, which may lead to this kind of behavior.

Comment: Yes also used your suggestion and get the same error,  and the process, let's say a humble calculator does not get killed.

Comment: Could it be related to synchronicity and asynchronicity?

Comment: @datelligence: according to code provided, I see that all is executed in sync way.

Answer (score 0):

How about a good ole `timer`... The consensus is using `WaitForExit` though...

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"cal.exe");
using (var t = new Timer(delegate { p.Kill(); }, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite))
{ 
  //what to do?
}
```

Comment: Again I used the same code you posted and by no , means the process is killed.

Comment: Im not sure I am understanding what you are saying?  The process is killed before the time ends or? What is `cal.exe` anyways, what happens if you just run it outside of your code, does it behave the same way?

Comment: cal.exe  is mispelled,  I edited, it launches windows calculator.  As you can see in the code I'm console printing the process status.  Running on Visual Studio,  I get the message that cannot kill a process who is terminated,  but the calculator is still there.